# How to vertically flip the integers in a 2D array C#

Tags: c#

I'm trying to vertically flip a 2D array, so I'm trying to turn this:

```
1 2 3 4 1
5 6 7 8 2 
4 3 2 1 1
8 7 6 5 2
```

into

```
8 7 6 5 2
4 3 2 1 1
5 6 7 8 2
1 2 3 4 1
```

So far, I've got a nested for loop,

```
for (int i= 0; i<rows; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j<columns; j++)
                {
                    WillSmith[i, j] = arr[i,j];
                    
                }
            }
```

With 'WillSmith' being the flipped array,
but I keep getting the same array as I entered back.

I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong

EDIT:
I've now swapped it to read arr[j,i], but now I get an error saying that I've overflowed the index. I need this to be able to work for non-square arrays, and since the array I'm testing isn't square, I can't just use newArray[i,j] = oldArray[j,i].

Comment: `WillSmith[i, j] = arr[i, j];` You are making a copy. i,j = i,j ...

Comment: Check your indexes. If i and j are at the same place in both arrays, it is normal that WillSmith ends up being a copy of arr.

Comment: If this is truly your desired outcome, you are not flipping the items per se, just entire rows; with row 1 becoming row 4, 2=>3, 3=>2, 4=>1.
So try by just incrementing row index, and having `n=arr.GetUpperBound(0)`, then use n-i as destination row index. Or something along that way...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
WillSmith[rows-1-i, j] = arr[i, j];
```

You want to keep your column index, just reverse rows column-wise. So read from start, write from end.

Comment: I still get the 'Index was outside the bounds of the array' error.

Comment: @EliahtBrantc Works for me: https://dotnetfiddle.net/fZRTqo Can you edit your question with the latest version of your code?

Comment: Your solution worked! I thought I was going insane, but it turns out I had my methods switched up and was displaying the original array instead of the output of the flipping method.

Answer (score 0):

The fastest way to do this, and for any type of array is to use `Buffer.BlockCopy()` to swap rows as needed.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var test = new int[,] {
            {1, 2, 3, 4, 1 },
            {5, 6, 7, 8, 2 },
            {4, 3, 2, 1, 1 },
            {8, 7, 6, 5, 2 } };

        var res = ReverseRows(test);

        Console.WriteLine();
        PrintArray(test);
        Console.WriteLine();
        PrintArray(res);
    }

    public static void PrintArray<T>(T[,] array, int colWidth=9)
    {
        int n = array.GetLength(0), m = array.GetLength(1);
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < m; j++)
            {
                Console.Write(array[i,j].ToString().PadLeft(colWidth));
            }
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
    }

    public static T[,] ReverseRows<T>(T[,] array)
    {
        int n = array.GetLength(0), m = array.GetLength(1);
        T[,] result = array.Clone() as T[,];

        for (int i = 0; i < n/2; i++)
        {
            SwapRows(result, i, n - i - 1); 
        }
        return result;
    }

    static void SwapRows<T>(T[,] array, int row1, int row2)
    {
        if (row1 == row2) return;
        int n = array.GetLength(0), m = array.GetLength(1);
        int byteLen = Buffer.ByteLength(array) / (n * m);

        T[] buffer = new T[m];
        // copy row1 to buffer
        Buffer.BlockCopy(array, row1 * m * byteLen, buffer, 0, m * byteLen);
        // copy row2 to row1
        Buffer.BlockCopy(array, row2 * m * byteLen, array, row1 * m * byteLen, m * byteLen);
        // copy buffer to row2
        Buffer.BlockCopy(buffer, 0, array, row2 * m * byteLen, m * byteLen);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

An example of fastest way to invert a 80*260 array vertically

```
  const int ROW = 80;
  const int COL = 260;
  public ushort[,] FlipFrameVertical(ushort[,] frame)
  {
    // ushort size is 2 bytes
    int byteSize = 2 * COL;
    ushort[,] frame_flipped = new ushort[ROW, COL];

    for (int i = 0; i < ROW; i++)
    {

        Buffer.BlockCopy(frame, (byteSize * (ROW-1-i)), frame_flipped, 
        byteSize * i, byteSize);
    }

     return frame_flipped;
   }
```

Change the byte size based on your data type.